# Quasar Framework: hide QToolbarTitle inside QLayoutHeader/QToolbar

Tags: quasar-framework

I'm trying to build an application with Quasar Framework.

I want to have 2 `QRouteTab`s in the `QToolbar` that is located inside `QLayoutHeader`. I have this code:

```
<template>
  <q-layout view="lHh Lpr lFf">
    <q-layout-header>
      <q-toolbar color="primary" :inverted="$q.theme === 'ios'">
        <q-tabs>
          <div class="row">
            <q-route-tab default="true" to="/" label="Найду еду"/>
            <q-route-tab to="/contacts" label="Контакты"/>
          </div>
        </q-tabs>
      </q-toolbar>
    </q-layout-header>

    <q-page-container>
      <router-view />
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>
</template>
```

This is what I get:

[image: Result screenshot]

As you see, there is an empty space above the `QTabs`. I want to get rid of it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do what you want is to remove the surrounding div and add `slot="title"` to the q-route-tab element.
This will stick the tab in the right place.

```
<q-tabs>
  <q-route-tab slot="title" default="true" to="/" label="Найду еду"></q-route-tab>
  <q-route-tab slot="title" to="/contacts" label="Контакты"></q-route-tab>
</q-tabs>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/stevebor1/pen/zyJBgX)

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the page code in the browser and came up with the solution:

```
<style>
  .q-tabs-head {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: You may want to mark this as the answer so others will know the problem is solved

Comment: I cannot: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days".

Comment: this is a hack. there is a slot property that can be used. See my answer.